Roslyn GetSymbolInfo from InvocationExpressionSyntax returns null on generic method calls with inferred types
I walk through the codebase looking for InvocationExpressionSyntax nodes and try to lookup the called IMethodSymbol with GetSymbolInfo.
In most cases, this succeeds and I get a IMethodSymbol.
But in many other cases I get null.
What all the cases where I get null have in common is, that it's an invocation of a generic method, where the type parameters are not given but inferred by the compiler.
So I assume that this is the problem, but strangely I can not find any information about this problem on the internet.
So how can I get the SymbolInfo from an InvocationExpressionSyntax if it is a call to a generic method with inferred type parameters?

The first thing I'd check is Compilation.GetDiagnostics(). Does that return any diagnostics? Also, in what context are you running? Analyzer? Source Generator? Regular tool (e.g, console app, etc)?
